# No module 'named tensorflow_core.esitmator'

Tags: tensorflow

Hello i believe in you can help my problem. I am using Windows10, 64bit. I run below codes in spyder. But there is an error of "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow_core.estimator'". I uninstalled tensorflow, tensorboard, tensorflow-estimator then again installed but error did not disappeared. How to solve it please?

Codes:
import time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tensorflow as tf
import dataset

Answer (score 1):

your question is missing some of the code. I will go in a limb here. In case you are running TF 2.00. You can check the version with

```
print(tf.__version__)
```

use [tf.compat.v1.estimator](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/compat/v1/estimator/) instead

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with tensorflow 1.15, downgrading tensorflow.estimator to 1.15.1 solved the problem.